# Apache Ant Custom Task: Class not found Exception from the class itself

Tags: java, ant, classloader

I've built an application with two modes:

1. Used from command line
2. Used from Ant

It works well from command line but from ANT the error is a surprise, the Java loader can't find the main class and the exception was thrown from the main class!

**Extract of main class**

```
package hpms.app.mon.client;
import ....;
public class MonitorMainFrame extends Application implements ProcessListener {
   ....
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      final Class<?> c = Class.forName( MonitorMainFrame.class.getName());
      /* The class was found and we print the constructor */
      System.err.println( c.getConstructor());
      launch( args );                                    // line 544
   }
}
```

**Build Execution**

```
Buildfile: D:\dev\java\2014\hpms.app.mon\build.xml

compile-sample:

run-servers:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
Buildfile: D:\dev\java\2014\hpms.app.mon\build.xml

compile-sample:

run-client:
[monitor-client] public hpms.app.mon.client.MonitorMainFrame() throws java.lang.Exception  <==== Trace of the constructor object

BUILD FAILED
D:\dev\java\2014\hpms.app.mon\build.xml:112: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hpms.app.mon.client.MonitorMainFrame
        at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:260)
        at hpms.app.mon.client.MonitorMainFrame.main(MonitorMainFrame.java:544)
        at hpms.app.mon.client.ant.AntTask.execute(AntTask.java:79)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="jar">
   ...

   <taskdef
      onerror  ="ignore"
      name     ="monitor-client"
      classpath="bin"
      classname="hpms.app.mon.client.ant.AntTask" />

   <target name="run-client" depends="compile-sample" description="...">
      <monitor-client
         minimized="true"
         autostart="true">
         ...
```

**How a Class Not Found Exception can be thrown from the class itself?**

I suppose the Java class loader has loaded the class and the Ant class loader hasn't...